# ¿Por qué en el siguiente ejemplo tengo que usar la función end?

Tags: python, python-3.7

¿Por qué no hacer esto?

```
def staircase(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(" "*(n-i-1), "#"*(i+1))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

    staircase(n)
```

¿Y tener que hacer esto?

```
def staircase(n):
    # Write your code here 
    for i in range(n):
        print(" "*(n-i-1), end="")
        print("#"*(i+1))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

    staircase(n)
```

Si ambos muestran lo mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print()` por default imprime un `\n` luego de impreso el string que le pasastes.

El parámetro `end=x` le dice que en lugar de mandar un `\n`, made `x`.

Se usa para imprimir por partes dentro de la misma línea.

En el primer ejemplo no se nota, pues solo hay un `print()`. En el segundo ejemplo si lo necesitas pues quieres imprimir lo mismo en dos pasos.

Puedes usar cualquier cadena en `end=x`.